# Mark Job as Unstable

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, continuous-integration, karma-runner

I have setup a CI pipeline in Jenkins for my angular application. I have two simple jobs at the moment. Both my jobs share a common work space. The first job basically does build (npm install, bower install etc). It is working fine. The second job basically runs unit test(gulp test). I am using karma for test and phantom. So both jobs are running fine at the moment.

Eventually I will add more jobs for my integration test and code analysis etc. So basically each successful job will trigger the next one in the pipeline to run.

I was wondering is it possible to mark a job as unstable if something fails. For example in my second job where I run my unit testing, say that even one test case fails i would like to mark it unstable to that it doesn't trigger any further jobs. Is this possible to do and if so what is the most intelligent and efficient way to do it? And since i never had a test case fail i wouldn't know this but does JENKINS mark job unstable automatically if one test case fails ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Jenkins mark [a build as] unstable automatically if one test case fails?

Yes. It will depend on the exact testing plugin you're using for Jenkins, but I imagine all of them should implement this correctly.

> I would like to mark [a build] unstable to that it doesn't trigger any further [downstream] jobs

It sounds like you're already using the "Build other projects" post-build action. There you just need to make sure that the default "Trigger only if build is stable" option is selected.
Then, if any tests fail, the build will be unstable, and a downstream build will not be triggered.

Comment: what testing plugin do you recommend I use ?

Comment: It depends on what test runner you're using. If you can output your test results in JUnit XML format, you can parse that easily with Jenkins. There are a list of other testing plugins linked from the [xUnit plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) including JSUnit. All of which should work just as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions mate. So to get this clear, at the moment I am not using Karma in my application, and if one test case fails my build will be marked as unstable automatically ?

Comment: Just running the tests isn't enough — you need to output the results to a file then, via a "post-build action", let Jenkins analyse the results. Jenkins will then be able to alter the build result based on the test results. The post-build actions available to you depend on which plugins you have installed (the JUnit plugin usually comes pre-installed), hence why you need to find a plugin that suits the test runner. But it looks like Karma can output JUnit XML, so it should be pretty easy: https://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/Jenkins-CI.html

Comment: You partially answered my new question earlier thought you might be able to answer this properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567894/fail-pipeline-in-jenkins