# Fail Pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have used Jenkins to create a CI pipeline for my node js application. My pipeline includes jobs such as build,unit test,integration test,code analysis etc. I was wondering if it is possible to fail a build if for example  by implementing threshold like z number of tests failed or pass rate < z% ? I know by default a build will fail if even one test case fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit test script will need to handle the math & logic to determine what percent of tests failing is bad enough to fail the whole job.  Then your unit test script can return pass (zero) or fail (anything else) and Jenkins will mark the build accordingly.

Comment: is this the most efficient way to achieve this? are there any plugins ?

Comment: There could be some plugins, but the plugins would need to know internal details of your tests and which ones you consider bad enough to fail and which an be ignored.

The problem is that knowledge internal to your tests should stay in the testing system (separation of concerns).  So your tests should just tell jenkins pass / fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to test with mocha in jenkins:

https://johnhamelink.com/2012/11/13/testing-nodejs-with-jenkins

Here is a related question: [Why when test fails jenkins still says success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859337/why-when-test-fails-jenkins-still-says-success)

Answer (score -1):

Try [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

This plugin also helps to run your pipelined jobs