# Why when test fails jenkins still says success?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, mocha.js

I have a MEAN project. Using Jenkins on an EC2 machine I build this using the following shell script:

```
npm install && PORT=8888 npm test
```

mocha returns 2 (number of failing tests) but still jenkins says:

> Finished: SUCCESS.

If tests are failing I expect to see

> Finished: FAILURE

Do you know why its not working fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

1. Use a test runner like Karma, or
2. Tell Mocha to report in, for example, XUnit format, by passing Mocha the `--reporter xunit` flag. XUnit closely aligns with JUnit which Jenkins understands, or
3. Add in a custom reporter — [mocha-jenkins-reporter](https://github.com/juhovh/mocha-jenkins-reporter) is a decent option.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. I used 3rd option: added Makefile to the project and on shell script in Jenkins I replace "npm install test" with "make jenkins" but this doesn't do anything, do you have any clue why?

Comment: @CristianBoariu It's hard to say without seeing how you've set everything up. Option 2 is probably the "easiest".

Comment: I have run into the problem where my junit test result returned a FAIL, but the job was only marked Unstable instead of Fail because the shell script that ran the test returned a 0 (SUCCESS). The failure in the result.xml was only able to demote the job from Pass (because none of the steps failed) to Unstable.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I used a different solution: installed Jenkins Text Finder and if "expected - actual" is found in log (test failed), I let this plugin to mark the build as "Unstable".

Comment: "Jenkins Text Finder" maybe?